# Access USB with Java, in order to find thumbdrive manufacturer's serial#/unique-ID

Tags: java, usb

Looking for a way to read the unique ID / serial# of a USB thumb drive;
please note that
- I am looking for the value of the manufacturer, not the one Windows allocates for it.
- I need to support multiple OS (Windows, Unix, Mac), thus needs to be a Java solution

The idea is to be able to distinguish between different USB thumb drives.

Answer (score 3):

RXTX is the way to go. In the world of model trains, JMRI (Java Model Railroad Interface) has become very popular. JMRI runs on all platforms (Windows, Linux and Mac) and communicates with a variety of USB based devices (command stations). RXTX is in fact used by JMRI.

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried using it (it's been on my todo list for a good few months now), but there is the "marge" project on java.net:

http://marge.java.net/

This should let you connect to bluetooth devices (although I don't think it is 100% feature complete, there is demo code on there), and then the ClientDevice class has a "getBluetoothAddress" method which I *believe* should be unique to that device

http://marge.java.net/javadoc/v06/marge-core/net/java/dev/marge/entity/ClientDevice.html

As I say though, I've never tried it...

Comment: please do not provide any link in your answer. The link provided by you are broken. When you were answering the question at that time this links may be working but now those links are not working.

Comment: @Banshi five years ago, the link was probably very helpful.  I'm not going to make myself less useful in the present by never providing links. I'm also not going to go back an check all the links I've ever posted anywhere.  The web is brittle. Deal with it.

Comment: @Banshi But as you pointed it out, I'll change the links this time ;-)

Comment: it is true at that time link was working but now it is not working for me, though I am new comer to this site and you are also much more senior to me. But when i am searching for a answer and the link posted by the answer writer are broken then we are becoming disappointed.

Answer (score 2):

You might give a look at the following projects:
[javax-usb](http://javax-usb.org/) and [jusb](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/). They seem to support Linux and Windows.

Anyway, since USB access in Java requires the use of native libraries, you might not achieve the required portability.

Answer (score 1):

I have never investigated this thoroughly, but from memory the [RXTX](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/) library implementation of the javax.comm packages are supposedly very good and now have USB support.